# Is there a typescript schema/idl for the token program instructions?

Tags: solana-program, authority

Good morning, trying to decode data from the last instruction of [this transaction](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/64ammifoZQsmWDxFCUgfkVtRFth9tquHNxYdFrA6FMR2ZLS2y4w88QEc7BP5ryB8rtJCrdU2J24xd7a98us49Bws) which is a setAuthority instruction.
My main problem is that i can't get the `newAuthority` address from the data, since i can't find any schema or idl i can use for this.
Is there a place i can go to find this? already looked at the [token github repo](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/token) and [token docs](https://spl.solana.com/token) but can't find nothing there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an [IDL](https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor/blob/master/client/packages/spl-token/idl.json) for the SPL Token program generated using [Native to Anchor](https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor) created by [acheroncrypto](https://twitter.com/acheroncrypto).

Answer (score 0):

Compile your smart contract and there must be a `.ts` file in `target/types/` folder. Your types in there.